# Returning an image response from storage along with other data?

Tags: laravel

In a controller I return a view with data. Along with this data, how can I also send back an image?

The image needs to be loaded via `Storage` as it's private, I get the image and build an image response in a class.

How can I also return this image response along side my data?

I've tried setting the response to a var in my data and displaying that in `img src` but it fails to load the image.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I work with url. `Storage::url('file.ext')` give you a lot of possibility. There is also a way to create temporary url with this method within the Storage facade `$url = Storage::temporaryUrl('file.jpg', now()->addMinutes(5));` You have to indicate when the url should expire.

There is another method that I use with drawboard.
You first have to get the content of your image. I don't remember, but I think the get() method of storage do the job. Maybe it's a bit more complex.

Whatever, you have to get the raw data of the image, put it into a variable and send it to the view.

Then, in the src of the image, you do this:

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{$varToRawData}}" />
```

Be sure to use the right image/extension